# Can not delete Glacier Vault even after removing all archives

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I am trying to delete my Glacier Vault with around 16k archives using this  [python](https://github.com/leeroybrun/glacier-vault-remove) script.

After the inventory retrieval job is complete it removes all the archives but in the last step of removing the vault I get this error:

```
ERROR : Exception "InvalidParameterValueException" occured with message "An error occurred 
InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the DeleteVault operation: Vault not empty or recently written
08:03:06 - ERROR : We cant remove the vault now. Please wait some time and try again. You can 
also remove it from the AWS console, now that all archives have been removed.
```

But I also can not remove it from the AWS console which gives me the exact same error.

Comment: How long have you waited? I'd try again after 24-48 hours. Glacier is low-cost, but operates slowly.

Comment: hm I waited now 12 hours after the retrival job was done and I run the python script

Comment: It _might_ go faster if you can run a Job that lists the contents of the vault. This should help it realise that the vault is empty. Or, you could just wait longer.